# how to get input can be written automatically in Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-8

How to get input from textfield, radio button, etc can be written automatically in Jtable row ?
I've created a default column model, but i don't know the next step.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Hi Sir, I've changed my question

Comment: Thank You @trashgod . Hope you can help me .